# GoLang: Generic In Inner Struct and Dynamic Type

Tags: go, generics

I want to make a child struct use a generic type as variable can be one of two types depending on the situation. I have the following solution

```
type Resource interface {
    Phone | Computer
}

type MetricData[R Resource] struct {
    ResourceName string      `json:"resourceName"`
    Metrics      []Metric[R] `json:"metrics"`
}

type Metric[R Resource] struct {
    Resource    R   `json:"resource"`
    Occurrences int `json:"occurrences"`
    Change      int `json:"change"`
}
```

However, I won't know the type of Resource at runtime. When I create a new struct instance I need to provide the type of R

```
model.MetricData[model.Phone]{ResourceName: resource, Metrics: tm}
```

Is there a way to give MetricData the type at runtime and determine it via if/else statement depending on some condition?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use generics where interfaces are needed.

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/3FjjkWbgBYe)):

```
func resourceType[T Resource](r T) string {
    switch any(r).(type) {
    case Phone:
        return "phone"
    case Computer:
        return "computer"
    default:
        return ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your structures like this:

```
type Resource interface {}

type MetricData struct {
    ResourceName string      `json:"resourceName"`
    Metrics      []Metric    `json:"metrics"`
}

type Metric struct {
    Resource    Resource   `json:"resource"`
    Occurrences int        `json:"occurrences"`
    Change      int        `json:"change"`
}
```

Now, to know the exact type of Resource, you can do something like this:

```
dummyMetric := {Resource: models.Phone{}, Occurrence: 1, Change: 1}
resourceType := ""

switch dummyMetric.Resource.(type) {
case models.Phone:
    resourceType = "phone"
case models.Computer:
    resourceType = "computer"
}
```

Hope it helps!